# writing-mode: vertical-rl dont work corectly in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have a problem in firefox with vertically oriented text `writing-mode: vertical-rl; text-orientation: mixed; transform: rotate(180deg);`. I am attaching the images below. Has anyone had a similar problem?

Firefox

[image]

Other browsers

[image]

Comment: Is there anyone who has had a similar case?

Comment: I am experiencing a similar bug, and I found [an open bug in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1767091) that I think is related.  It sounds like Firefox waits to calculate the width of `writing-mode: vertical-rl` elements until _after_ most other spacing stuff has been calculated.

Answer (score 1):

set `width: fit-content;` in box.